# error_reporting bool operations

Tags: error-handling, php-5.4

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867082/288568 I found two ways of disabling notices. So what exactly is the a difference between

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

and

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

?

And what does the following line do?

```
error_reporting((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_DEPRECATED  ^ E_NOTICE );
```

Would this correctly report E_ALL and E_STRICT but not DEPRECATED AND NOTICEs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE));
var_dump(error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE));
```

is the same int(32759). Just different binary operations to get there.

> Would this correctly report E_ALL and E_STRICT but not DEPRECATED AND NOTICEs ?

```
var_dump( decbin ((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_DEPRECATED  ^ E_NOTICE) );
```

is

```
101111111110111

111111111111111 E_ALL
000100000000000 E_STRICT
000000000001000 E_NOTICE
010000000000000 E_DEPRECATED
```

So the anwser is yes and `(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED  ^ E_NOTICE)` would be the same.